# High CPU utilization - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cpu-usage

We are facing an issue with VB.NET listeners that utilizes high CPU (50% to 70%) in the server machine where it is running. Listeners are using a threading concept and also we used `FileSystemWatcher` class to keep monitoring the file renaming pointing to one common location. Both are console applications and scheduled jobs running all the day.

How can I control the CPU utilization with this `FileSystemWatcher` class?

Comment: Have you run a profiler to find out where the time is going?

Answer (score 1):

This could all depend on the code you are running.

For instance if you have a timer with an interval of 10ms but only do work every two minutes and on each timer interval you do a lot of checking this will take a lot of CPU to do nothing.

If you are using multiple threads and one is looping waiting for the second to release a lock (`Monitor.TryEnter()`) then again this may be taking up extra CPU. You can avoid this by putting the waiting thread into `Monitor.Wait()` and then when the busy thread is finished do `Monitor.Pulse()`.

Apart for the very general advice above, if you post the key parts of your code or profile results then we may be able to help more.

If you are looking for a profiler we use RedGates ANTS Profiler (costs but with a free trial) and it give good results, I haven't used any other to compare (and I am in no way affiliated with RedGate) so others may be better.